# Why is my function giving these parameter errors?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

pg_execute() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given and pg_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

```
$display_calls = pg_prepare($conn, "display_calls", "SELECT clients.firstName, clients.lastName, callLogs.callDate FROM clients INNER JOIN callLogs ON clients.id=callLogs.Clients_id");
function display_logs(){
    global $display_calls;
    $output = "";
    global $conn;
    $result = pg_execute($conn, $display_calls);
    $records = pg_num_rows($result);
    for($i = 0; $i < $records; $i++){  //loop through all of the retrieved records and add to the output variable
        $output .= "\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "First Name")."</td>"; 
        $output .= "\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "Last Name")."</td>"; 
        $output .= "\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "Date & Time")."</td>\n\t</tr>"; 
    }
    return $output;
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: `$result = pg_execute($conn, "display_calls");`

Comment: "expects parameter 3 to be an array"

Comment: But you do not have any need for param 3 as you have no parameters

Comment: Might be simpler to make it a `_query()`

Comment: So try `$result = pg_execute($conn, "display_calls", []);`

Comment: Slightly o/t, but why have horrible, horrible `global` definitions there when you could just pass `$display_calls` and `$conn` into your function as parameters? To me, splitting code into a function but then making it rely on outside variables having specific names is poor practice.

Comment: Aside: the line `echo $output;` is unreachable - the function has already returned before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

> pg_execute() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

This error is slightly confusing, because the parameter it's actually talking about is the *second* one: [the documentation for `pg_execute`](https://www.php.net/pg_execute) shows that what you need to pass is the *string naming the prepared statement*:

> stmtname: The name of the prepared statement to execute. if "" is specified, then the unnamed statement is executed. The name must have been previously prepared using pg_prepare(), pg_send_prepare() or a PREPARE SQL command.

This is *not* what is returned by [the `pg_prepare` function](https://www.php.net/pg_prepare):

> Return Values: An PgSql\Result instance on success, or false on failure. [...] previously, a resource was returned

So instead of:

```
$result = pg_execute($conn, $display_calls);
```

You want:

```
$result = pg_execute($conn, "display_calls");
```

---

> pg_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

This is just a consequence of the previous problem: since you didn't check for errors, you passed a failed result (indicated by `null`) into `pg_num_rows`.

Comment: I've tried this and the same error still occurs